# XlsxWriter: Creating new worksheets

Tags: python, excel, worksheet-function, xlsxwriter

I'm trying to create new worksheets using the XlsxWriter to write data to a new sheet with every new iteration of a loop.

The code that I have is as follows:

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Report.xlsx')
for i in range(0, len(list)):
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    #Extract data from the list and add it to the excel sheet
    workbook.close()
```

Now, the problem with this method is that I see only a  single worksheet, and not multiple sheets.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: try `workbook.add_worksheet(i)` and see if you get sheets with different names

Comment: Do you want to work in multiple sheets at once

Comment: @VigneshKalai With every iteration, I want to write to a new sheet.

Comment: @Vaulstein, that did not work, the exception is: `TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()` for the line: `worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet(i)`

Comment: As @Vaulstein stated you can add worksheets with integer as sheet names or you could just add new sheet with  worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet() it will automatically give names as Sheet 1, Sheet 2 as excel do

Comment: Give workbook.add_worksheet(str(i))

Comment: @VigneshKalai, thing is, the names don't matter, the new sheets aren't being created presently, that's more of a problem.

Comment: They don't show until you save the woork book  that is this method workbook.close() saves and closes the workbook until then it is in memory onlt

Comment: try having the close outside the for loop and if this doesn't work try adding a test sheet outside the for loop before `workbook.close()`

Comment: `list` is a reserved word.  Are you actually using it, or is that just to represent some other variable that happens to be a list?

Comment: It represents another element which is a list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per correction from the comment, even though the XlsxWriter API allows for closing the workbook in between modifications, it will only write the changes until the first close.

```
import xlsxwriter
import openpyxl

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
for i in range(10):
    workbook.add_worksheet()
    workbook.close()
assert len(workbook.worksheets()) == 10
assert len(openpyxl.load_workbook('test.xlsx').sheetnames) == 1

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
for i in range(10):
    workbook.add_worksheet()
workbook.close()
assert len(workbook.worksheets()) == 10
assert len(openpyxl.load_workbook('test.xlsx').sheetnames) == 10
```

You need to move the `workbook.close()` out of the loop, after all the workbook modifications:

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Report.xlsx')
for i in range(0, len(list)):
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    #Extract data from the list and add it to the excel sheet
workbook.close()
```

Comment: *it is possible to keep adding worksheets, etc.while intermediately closing the workbook:*: Strictly speaking it isn't. The object may contain 10 worksheets, like in your assert, but the file will only contain 1. The workbook should only be closed once.

Comment: @jmcnamara You are correct sir. The resulting file only has 1 sheet indeed, even when the model allows further modifications. Lame of me to automatically expect such consistency.

Comment: Or perhaps lame of me not to make multiple closes an exception or warning. `:-|`